# MVC 4 Custom validation on Partial View don't show error message ?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, error-messaging

When i click Submit button on index page, see following image:
[image: index page]

**My question:**
I'm just custom required attribute, why error message for **ProductDescription** don't show ?

All my file, see the below section:

**ProductModel.cs**

```
namespace TestCustomValidation.Models
{
    public class ProductModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "It's for test for ProductName")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [CustomRequired(ErrorMessage = "It's for test for ProductDescription")]
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
...
@{Html.RenderAction("Form");}
...
```

**_FormPartial.cshtml**

```
@model TestCustomValidation.Models.ProductModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", new { @id = "form", @name = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductName)
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProductDescription)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult Form()
        {
            ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
            return PartialView("_FormPartial", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FormSubmit(ProductModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string name = model.ProductName;
                return RedirectToAction("About");
            }

            return PartialView("_FormPartial", model);
        }
}
```

**CustomRequiredAttribute.cs**

```
namespace TestCustomValidation.CustomValidation
{
    public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks for advance !

Comment: Have you registered your `CustomRequiredAttribute` in `global.asax.cs`? But what is the point of that attribute and what does it do?

Comment: Oh no @StephenMuecke, my mistake, thank you. I want custom required attribute to make error message show as image, like `public class ImageRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
             return new ValidationResult("<img src='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/error.gif") + "' />");
        }

    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer, for further reference:

In **Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Add Custom Attribute
    System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
                typeof(TestCustomValidation.CustomValidation.CustomRequiredAttribute),
                typeof(System.Web.Mvc.RequiredAttributeAdapter));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have jQuery validation included in your page and it's never actually going to your server, but instead showing you the message associated with that input field as a client side validation.